# PyObjC show warnings when classes called

Tags: python, warnings, appkit, quartz, pyobjc

Pyobjc does not support classes, and show warnings when I call them.

I use:

- macOS Big Sur 11.7.4
- Python 3.10 interpreter
- PyCharm as code redactor.

I installed pyobjc via this command:

```
pip3 install -U pyobjc==9.0.1 pyobjc-core==9.0.1
```

I wrote a small script for determining the mouse location on the screen.

```py
import AppKit, Quartz
location = AppKit.NSEvent.mouseLocation() # Cannot find reference 'NSEvent' in '__init__.py |                          __init__.py'
position = (round(location.x), round(Quartz.CGDisplayPixelsHigh(0) - round(location.y)))# Cannot find reference 'CGDisplayPixelsHigh' in '__init__.py | __init__.py | imported module Quartz'
```

However, I got mouse location, but warnings:

```
Cannot find reference 'NSEvent' in '__init__.py | __init__.py'
Cannot find reference 'CGDisplayPixelsHigh' in '__init__.py | __init__.py | imported module Quartz
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: Are these warnings from PyCharm?

I don't get these warnings when running this scriptlet from the command line.  

PyCharm probably warns because it cannot find the class definition for code completion and other editor magic.  That's expected at the moment because PyObjC loads classes dynamically from the Objective-C runtime and does not define them in a location that editors can statically inspect.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem in PyCharm?

Comment: Not that I know.